# How can I combine "concat" after "explode" in Migrate API YML?

Tags: migrations

I have a YML file for creating Commerce Variation and create their multiple images. However, I can not get "concat" to work after "explode" so that I can add the full file path to the exploded file names. This is what I have but it fails as the concat does not seem to properly use each exploded value:

```
  field_product_image:
    -
      plugin: explode
      source: Product Image
      delimiter: '|'
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/file_source_uri
        - Product Image
    -
      plugin: entity_generate
      entity_type: file
```

Comment: Assuming `Product Image` is a single-string, pipe-delimited multi-value source, exploded to multiple single values, you then have to `sub_process` those values. See https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21SubProcess.php/class/SubProcess/8.6.x

Comment: Could you provide any assistance on how to properly add sub_process to the code above?